# Pandas dataframe.drop randomly dropping rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to drop unneeded rows from a Pandas dataframe based on a series of conditions.
I have a drop statement for each set of conditions - 10  conditions in all. However, rows are randomly being dropped.  Each time I run the code on a test case where no rows should be dropped a different number of rows are dropped. I tried dropping using inplace=True but still get rows randomly dropped.  I tried commenting out all of the drop statements except the first one - using only one drop statement still results in randomly dropped rows.

This code seemed to work fine when I ran it locally on my PC.  However, I need to run it on a server.  The server has a more recent version of Python and Pandas.  I tried using the same version of Python and Pandas on the server that I am using on my PC but I still get randomly dropped rows.

What am I doing wrong?  I am baffled.

Here is example code - both methods result in randomly dropped rows:

```
df = df.drop(df[df['Pen ID'].str.len() <= 5].index)
df = df.drop(df[df['Operator ID'] == 'VC'].index)
df = df.drop(df[df['Test'] == 'Test1'].index)

df.drop(df[df['Pen ID'].str.len() <= 5].index, inplace=True)
df.drop(df[df['Operator ID'] == 'VC'].index, inplace=True)
df.drop(df[df['Test'] == 'Test1'].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: That is a very odd behaviour, you probably are doing something else that you aren't telling us. We can't reproduce the problem without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Anyway, instead of `df.drop(df[boolean_mask].index)`  you should do `df[~boolean_mask]`, where `~` is the logical NOT operator which inverts the boolean mask (True <-> False). It's simpler, faster and more readable.  See if it helps.

Comment: I changed my code from using df.drop to df[~boolean_mask] as you suggested.  That is the only change I made.  It worked!  Problem solved - thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `drop()` function I strongly suggest you just slice your dataframe to avoid multiple calls too.

Replace:

```
df = df.drop(df[df['Pen ID'].str.len() <= 5].index)
df = df.drop(df[df['Operator ID'] == 'VC'].index)
df = df.drop(df[df['Test'] == 'Test1'].index)
```

With:

```
df = df[(df['Pen ID'].str.len() > 5) & (df['Operator ID'] != 'VC') & (df['Test'] != 'Test1')]
```

This will keep all rows where then length of the value for `Pen ID` is larger than 5 (all values <= 5 are being dropped), AND the `Operator ID` is not VC (all `Operator ID == VC` will be dropped) AND the `Test` is not `Test1`.

Therefore, all rows in which at least one of dropping criteria is met will be dropped